# Convert DataSet to XML Without WriteXML()

Tags: asp.net, xml

I want to convert a dataset to an XML file without using WriteXML() built in function. Can anyone please tell me Is there any alternative ?

```
private void WriteDataSetToXmlFile(DataSet ds, string fileName)
{
    if (ds != null)
    {
        string b = TextBox2.Text;

        string absoluteFileName = Server.MapPath(fileName);
        System.IO.FileStream myFileStream = new System.IO.FileStream("D:\\XMLCON\\XMLCON\\" +b.ToString() +".xml", System.IO.FileMode.Create);
        System.Xml.XmlTextWriter myXmlWriter = new System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(myFileStream, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode);
        ds.WriteXml(myXmlWriter);
        myXmlWriter.Close();

    }
}
```

Comment: First: What's wrong with `WriteXML()` that you are looking for an alternative?  Without knowing why `WriteXML()` is not a valid solution, it's hard to offer suggestions.

Comment: actually i am doing a project. we are not allowed to use in built functions for conversions. so can i replace WriteXml() ?

Comment: Many people here (at least I do) want to solve real business problems that provide value to the questioner, not hypothetical situations with artificial limitations.  What's the business reason that you can't take advantage of the powerful built-in functions for your project?  Is this.. like coursework or something?  If so, we're not here to do your work for you.

Comment: In my case the framework that a use have bug in writexml and getxml in some situation.